# How to avoid the cache of symlinks in an NGINX reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, symlink, fastcgi

In a FastCGI server I used to symlink the folder containing the most updated code to a `current` folder in order to obtain zero downtime deployments.

I was using these directives to avoid the cache of the symlink:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
```

However now I'm in a reverse proxy and the symlink is getting cached, so the code being run currently is no longer the most updated one.

Is there a way to avoid the symlink cache in an NGINX reverse proxy?

Thanks in advance for your help, this is how the NGINX config looks like:

```
location @octane  {
    set $suffix "";

    if ($uri = /index.php) {
        set $suffix ?$query_string;
    }

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000$suffix;
}
```

Comment: take a look at the options proxy_no_cache and proxy_cache_bypass

Answer (score 0):

As NGINX is only communicating with the port for the reverse proxy symbolic links shouldn't affect this side of things. What deployment system are you using? As I'd expect that to stop the previous Octane server build (`php artisan octane:stop`) and load the new build using `php artisan octane:start`